# I'm trying to system restore my computer and want to keep my installed software

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, restore

I'm trying to system restore my computer (MacBook7,1 running 10.9.4), but want to keep Microsoft Office and Logic Express that I have installed. I do not have the disks to reinstall them, as I lost them during a move.

How can I restore my computer and keep my purchased software?

Comment: Please add the OS which is installed currently and the model id (e.g. MacBook5,1)

Comment: Carbon Copy app might do that. Also "normally" when you restore the OS X it only does so to the system files, not the applications.

Comment: I'm sorry, my model is the OS X 10.9.4.   It's the white macbook 2010, and it has mavericks installed. @klanomath